# Where to save user info in frontend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, browser, frontend

I am using react with redux for frontend. There is login functionality in the application and users can have different role. So when the user logs in, it will get userId and the role. I save the role in redux and according to the role the user can access the website. But when I refresh the page redux state becomes empty. So what would be the best way to save user role and userId in the frontend so that when I refresh the page user stays logged in. I used localstorage initially but user can change localstorage variable, if there is non-admin user and it change role in localstorage to admin then they will have admin rights. Sorry for dumb question I am new to this field.

Comment: You have to implement redux rehydrate.

Answer (score 0):

You may persist and rehydrate the redux store using [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist)

Follow the documentation steps of redux-persist.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will look into the documentation of the redux-persist. Looks like that is what I'll need.